# Reference request: Nonsmoothness of the projection operator

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, convex-analysis, projection

Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be nonempty closed and convex, and let $P_C\colon\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ be its projection operator. I've heard it is well-known that $P_C$ in general is not a smooth operator (i.e. if you think of $P_C(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x), ..., f_N(x))$, where each $f_i\colon\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$, then the Jacobian will not be defined everywhere since some of those $(f_i)_{1\leq i\leq N}$ will be nonsmooth). This can be seen even for simple examples in $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $C=[0,1]$). **I am looking for a journal article which points out this simple fact -- that such operators can be nonsmooth.**

Comment: Consider $N=1$ and $C=[0,1]$. It is so basic that I do not think you find a journal article, maybe a textbook.

Comment: @Miguel I've added that example to the question for clarity, thanks. Yeah it would be a fact that probably appears in the "introduction" to a nonsmooth nonlinear equations paper -- definitely not a journal result by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A. Shapiro. Directionally nondifferentiable metric projection. J. Optim. Theory Appl.,
81(1):203–204, 1994.*
https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02190320

constructs a convex set in $\mathbb R^2$, such that $P_C$ is not even directionally differentiable at one point.

Comment: Beautiful, I was not aware of the potential lack of directional differentiability too -- thanks!